# iis error: localhost refused to connect, ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: iis, server

I am installing a server using IIS 7, and I succeded to install it, and access it by localhost:80 or [my IP]:80. But when I use my smartphone, when I access to [my IP]:80, I get "localhost refused to connect: ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED". What should I do to solve this error?

I tried to restart IIS, but it didn't work.

I tried to check the log file, but there was no error.

Comment: What kind of IP address? If your phone and the server are not in the same network and your routing devices are not configured, anything can happen.

Comment: I used a port forwarding service from my router, and a few days ago it worked.

Comment: Then clearly you need to use tools like Wireshark to analyze the packets and their routing now. Things changed.

Comment: I suggest you could also use network monitor to see what happend when you send the request from the smart phone to the server. It seems that your route server or your application server  refused connection. Details about how to use network monitor, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/troubleshoot-tcpip-netmon).

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, I guess you may not add the ip address binding for your router.

I suggest you could try to add the both public ip and vitual ip into the binding and make sure your domain is right.

More details about how to add the binding, you could refer to below image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your binding you have one for port 443
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xnQw.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).